# Async Request with OpenAPI Generator Python

Tags: python, django, python-asyncio

Happy New Year EveryOne
I have a particular Case in which i am using OpenAPI generator for calling the api in another Microservice.
I have two microservices ie User and Customer
so in Customer im am getting the information of the multiple users from User below is the example code

```
from user.api_clients import User
user_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
user_list = [User.api.get(id=i) for i in user_id]
```

and the above code will give me the user_data from User. In short it will hit user api from User 9 times one by one.
So is there any way to hit this in a single shot with asyncio. I am new to this async thing in python. So ill really appreciate if anyone can give me an idea about how to do this.
There is also a similar case like i want to get object from User model in oneshot for these user_id list. Yes i can use id__in=user_id but is ther anyway to hit the below code in oneshot like below code

```
user_id = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
user_obj = [User.objects.get(id=i) for i in user_id]
```

Thanks for helping